# Selenium Script with proxy is not working after converting .py to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

Hope you all are well.
I have written a python script which is using authenticated proxies and now I have converted it into .exe and it's giving me error "ERROR TUNNEL Connection".
So the behavior of .exe file is,

1. With no proxy, it's working fine
2. With proxy, it's giving "ERROR TUNNEL Connection"

Is anyone here know the solution?

```
def get_proxy_variables(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS):
manifest_json = """
    {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Chrome Proxy",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
    }
    """

background_js = """
    var config = {
            mode: "fixed_servers",
            rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: "%s",
                port: parseInt(%s)
            },
            bypassList: ["localhost"]
            }
        };

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

    function callbackFn(details) {
        return {
            authCredentials: {
                username: "%s",
                password: "%s"
            }
        };
    }

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                callbackFn,
                {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                ['blocking']
    );
    """ % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)
return manifest_json, background_js


def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
proxy = get_random_proxy()
print(proxy)
manifest_json, background_json = get_proxy_variables(proxy[0], proxy[1], proxy[2], proxy[3])
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
if use_proxy:
    pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'
    with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
        zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
        zp.writestr("background.js", background_json)
    chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
if user_agent:
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
return driver
```

Comment: Have you tried to launch with administrator privileges or to permit it on windows firewall settings?

Comment: if it works with proxy from the script, i think that the problem here can be one of them, or maybe both.

Comment: I have tired to launch it with admin privilege's but the issue was same.

Comment: And when when I run .exe a pop came to allow access to it because firewall is blocking some of it's features etc. so I clicked on allow,

Comment: You was right. Can you paste it as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I've pasted the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to launch with administrator privileges or to permit it on windows firewall settings?

if it works with proxy from the script, i think that the problem here can be one of them, or maybe both